# Windows 10 WiFi drop-out

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

After re-boot my Windows 10 machine cannot connect to WiFi. If I run the troubleshooter it resets the network adapter and connects. After ~2 mins the WiFi drops again. This sequence continues as long as I am prepared to keep reseting the adapter. I tried

```
Updating the drivers
Changing the usb Wifi adapter to a different manufacturer
Preventing power down in the adapter settings
```

Then I discovered that if I connect to a hard wire CAT6 connection (to the same WiFi router) for a couple of minutes and then go back to WiFi the problem disappears (WiFi stays up) until the next re-boot.
Any ideas?

Comment: Wired and wireless share the same TCP/IP structure.  Run TCP/IP Reset and see if that fixes both connections.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator . 
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt . 
Then: ipconfig /flushdns . 
Then: restart the computer .  Test now.

Comment: Also, removing windows ability to control the power management of the device sometimes helps. You can turn this off by going to Device Manager > Right clicking wifi card and choosing Properties > Power Management tab > uncheck "allow this computer to turn off this device to save power"

Comment: If the above steps still didn't work, you could try to reinstall Wi-Fi driver and then see if the issue is solved. For how to reinstall Wi-Fi driver step by step, please refer to the following link:https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-reinstall-wi-fi-driver-on-windows-10-easily/

Comment: This question needs more details. As it is, it's very similar to other questions that have already been answered. What's the router make/model? What's the wlan adapter make/model? Have you installed any major updates to windows 10 recently?

Answer (score 0):

Wired and wireless share the same TCP/IP structure.

**(1) TCP/IP Reset**

To correct overall issues, run TCP/IP Reset and see if that fixes both connections.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator . Then:

netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt . Then:

ipconfig /flushdns . Then:

Restart the computer and test your connections.

**(2) DISM, SFC**

Also, at this point run DISM and SFC.

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator .

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /StartComponentCleanup

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW

Restart when these 3 commands are done. They do correct issues, but if there are no issues to correct, no harm in running the commands.